# C++ error: object of abstract class type is not allowed

Tags: c++

Having trouble with inheritance. I do not know what is wrong with the script..

**in main**

```
int main(){
    Repository repo("dogs.txt");
    FileAdoptionList* a = new CSVDoglist{}; / here is the error
    Controller ctrl(repo, dogValidator{}, a);
    UI ui(ctrl);

    ui.startUI();

    delete a;
}
```

**CSVDoglist.h**

```
class CSVDoglist : public FileAdoptionList
{
public:

    void writeToFile();
    void displayAdoptionlist() const;
};
```

**FileAdoptionList.h**

```
class FileAdoptionList : public AdoptionList
{
protected:
    std::string filename;

public:
    FileAdoptionList();
    virtual ~FileAdoptionList() {}

    void setFilename(const std::string& filename);
    virtual void writeToFile() = 0;
    virtual void displayAdoptionList() const = 0;
};
```

**AdoptionList.h**

```
class AdoptionList
{
protected:
    std::vector<Dog> storage;

public:
    AdoptionList();

    // Adds a dog to the playlist.
    void add(const Dog& dog);
    // Checks if the adoptionlist is empty.
    bool isEmpty();

    virtual ~AdoptionList() {}
};
```

**ERRORS:**

```
object of abstract class type "CSVDoglist" is not allowed:  

'CSVDoglist': cannot instantiate abstract class Adoptig Dogs
```

I have read more topics about this problem but I didn't found the solution.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: The question is what `CSVDoglist{}` stands for? Maybe you meant `CSVDoglist()`?

Comment: That's valid initialization since c++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a typo.

A function named `displayAdoptionlist` (contains small `l`) is declared in `CSVDoglist`, but the pure virtual function `displayAdoptionList` (contains large `L`) isn't overrided in `CSVDoglist`.

Comment: This is why you should use the `override` keyword.

Comment: @Gill Meh; then the code would still fail for the same reason and the OP would still be wondering why.

Comment: Damn, Thank you so much.